# What is the models folder inside the .aws folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I connected to an EC2 with Windows OS and was running the awscli commands. I noticed that in my `.aws` profile folder, I see a `models` folder created. What is the `models` folder for and somehow if I moved this folder out from the `.aws` folder I am getting different results when running the awscli.

Answer (score 2):

The `.aws/models` folder is used to store AWS CLI service models and shouldn't be removed.

AWS CLI service models are a set of JSON files that provide a structured description of an AWS service's API. These service models are essentially schemas that describe how to transform a CLI command into an HTTP request and transform the HTTP response back into the output that you see in the terminal.

If you have a AWS CLI version that doesn’t support a specific service, then you can either update the CLI, or you can download the service model file, and use the [add-model option in aws configure](https://go.aws/3qq0W6Y).

Some tools do this automatically to add access to service API capabilities that are required but may not be part of the AWS CLI, yet.

For this reason, I would recommend leaving the folder where it is. Otherwise, the CLI may behave in unexpected ways or not work at all.